# What is the fastest (and affordable) way to get to Catbalogan, Samar from Mindanao?

Tags: transportation, children, philippines

I'm going to the Philippines in December and there's a 21K race I would like to do. The [race](http://siguecorrer.com/2013/03/16/srcs-king-of-the-hill-2013-challenge-5k10k21k-catbalogan-samar-december-29-2013/) is in Catbalogan and apparently there's [no flights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catbalogan#Air) to their airport. I tried to look in [WikiTravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Catbalogan) with no luck. I'll be in Mindanao and I was looking for either flights or ferries (Cagayan de oro seems to be the place to start).

We'll be 5 adults and 1 baby travelling, so the option of one small airplane to charter is not an option as they only allow max of 4 people (from those who I asked) and the price is quite high for a return flight.

What I found most is Ferries (which, by the way, don't look nice) from Cebu to Catbalogan, but that it's too much travel, I think, for the baby.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fly from Mindanao to Cebu and then to [Tacloban](http://goo.gl/maps/LykQl) instead. Tickets from Cebu are about 150$. From there you can take a public bus or jeepneys to Catbalogan. You can also [rent a car there](http://www.tourisminthephilippines.com/city/Tacloban/rent-a-car/car-rental-tacloban.html) with driver for 100$/day. While this is not a direct transport either, its surely better than the 12 hours boat from Cebu.

Tacloban might also be the better place to celebrate new year since it's a bit bigger than Catbalogan and has specific [tourist information](http://www.tourisminthephilippines.com/city/Tacloban/new-year-celebration/new-year-in-the-philippines.html) on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @uncovery I hope the $150 ticket is not for each of us (5 in total) hehe. But I'll check that option. I'm not planing to spend new year in there.. I'll probably be back to Mindanao on the 29th..

Comment: @SERPRO Unfortunately the tickets that I looked at are 150$ per seat. You will not find 30$ flight tickets. But if you book for Mindanao-Cebu-Tacloban and back, you might get them cheaper than what I can see on the web, specially if you buy locally. If all else fails, you might consider going to the run by yourself, too.